# psql.exe postgresql create database via CMD

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, cmd, psql

I search to create a database via **CMD**, i success to create it using this command:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe" -U postgres template1
```

So when i excute this command i can Create my database like this:

```
template1=# CREATE DATABASE d_base;
```

My objectif is to create this database with just one line:

like this:

```
 C:\>"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe" -U postgres template1 "CREATE DATABASE T;"
```

But this not work with me, it gave me this error:

[image]

i can solve this problem with creating a **.bat** Script but my objectif is to use just one line,

Is there any solution for that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that error because `template1` is not the last argument. You can use `-d` to specify the database.

Use the database `postgres` instead of `template1`.

Try this:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe" -U postgres -d postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE t"
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html

see `--command=command` section